# MySQL restore does not accepts column comments

Tags: mysql

When trying to restore a .SQL (MySQL) dump file from one server to another, via mysql command line (mysql -u user -p < file.sql), I'm getting the below error in one of the tables:

```
syntax to use near 'COMMENT
```

The CREATE command it is trying to execute is:

```
CREATE TABLE `cookie` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `cloba_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cookie_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `FBID` (`user_id`) COMMENT 'facebook ID'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Via phpMyAdmin in the server that created the dump file, it works well.

I ended up excluding all comments in columns and then I managed to restore the DB. Is there a way that I can make it work with those column comments? I first thought it would be a problem of different versions, but I took a look dev.mysql.com, in documentation, and COMMENT should be compatible with my server version (5.1.73), as you can see in the syntax manual:

```
data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
  [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
  [COMMENT 'string']
  [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
  [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
  [reference_definition]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: index comments were added in mysql 5.5. either upgrade, or remove the comments. your document snippet is for fields, not indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of MySQL before 5.5.3 only allowed comments on the column definition. They are not allowed on key or index definitions. You will either need to remove them or upgrade to a newer MySQL version.

One other thing of interest in regards to the change in comments with MySQL 5.5.3 is that column (index/key) comments now allow for up to 1024 characters rather than just 255 characters. Table comments have increased from 60 characters to 2048 characters.

See the [MySQL Create Table docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) for more information.

Also, just in case you also use procedural comments (i.e. ones beginning with a #, --, or enclosed with /* ... */) when restoring by default the mysql command will ignore these types of comments. To make sure they are not ignored use the `--comments` flag. See this from the man file:

```
--comments, -c     Whether to preserve comments in statements sent to the server. The default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable with --comments (preserve comments).
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that. lol, I'm starting to regret my "Yes, give me CentOS instead of Ubuntu" decision in my VPS :/

Comment: You can probably take a look at [this link](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/07/31/how-to-install-mysql-server-5-6-on-centos-7-rhel-7/) to install a new version of MySQL.